# @Html.AntiForgeryToken() not rendering hidden input in any browser using Dot Net Nuke

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dotnetnuke

I have placed @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in my form but I am not seeing the hidden input in any browser source. What am I missing? I am using Dot Net Nuke v9. on .net v 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dnn by default add an antiforgerytoken. You can get it by calling $.ServicesFramework(). It contains the key and value which you have to send in your request to validate your request on server side by adding a  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on your controller action.

Comment: That was it! Thanks

Comment: Its ok,Let me know if you have more issues.